# Sip INVITE error and send BYE message

Tags: java, sip, sip-server

Hi i have two questions,

1-) When i send sip INVITE message and get errors bigger than 2xx then if i send BYE message is it reasonable to do this ? Server will response BYE message ?

2-) ACK will be sent for all 2xx status code and dont be sent for status codes bigger than 2xx. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

1) If a UAC receives a response to `INVITE` with response code >= 300, then there is no dialog, and thus neither the UAC or UAS can send `BYE`.

2) `ACK` must be sent for all final responses (200 or greater) to `INVITE`.  For response codes >= 300, then the transaction layer handles sending the ACK.  For 2xx responses, it is the responsibility of the transaction user (TU) layer.

You tagged the question with `java` - is that relevant to your question?  If you are using the JAIN-SIP API, for example, then your application (a TU) will not send the `ACK` in question 2, because the stack does that automatically.